# Is this a IKImageBrowserView?

Tags: macos, ikimagebrowserview, nsprogressindicator

I want to know is this a IKImageBrowserView object? And How can I add an NSProgressIndicator when loading the image?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like it could be one. How you add a progress indicator depends entirely on how you download the image. If you are using NSURLConnection then you can get status updates through connection:didReceiveResponse: and connection:didReceiveData:. The response structure contains the expected length of the file, which you would use as the maximum of your progress indicator, and the data contains the length of the data that you recieved in that chunk. Add that length to the lengths of the previous chunks you get will give you how much data you have received so far. That would be the position on your progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not `IKImageBrowserView`.It is a `NSCollectionView`.I also faced this problem then I googled and searched in internet to add `NSProgressIndicator` in `IKImageBrowserView` I did not get any solution. Finally I found `NSCollectionView` is the way to add  `NSProgressIndicator` animation when images loading.So I moved to `NSCollectionView`. [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to more details.